# RapidFlow Import Error: Empty or invalid product type for a new product

Tags: import, products, csv

I'm trying to do a product import of some downloadables into Magento via RapidFlow. Their documentation is less than stellar, and I can't seem to figure out how to get rid of this error: Empty or invalid product type for a new product. My understanding was that the Type Alias column of the Import Columns tab was the value you use in tow 1 in your csv. My very first cell in my CSV (A1) is product.type

In the Import Columns tab I've added Product Type [product.type], with the alias product.type to match my CSV. So how come I keep getting the same error for every row? Every row has a value of downloadable for the product.type. I think if I can figure out this column, I'll be able to figure out all the other ones I have errors on.

Help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Solved this. Apparently despite uploading new import CSVs every time, there's a setting on the Profile Information tab called File Name, and this value has to be manually changed to match the filename of your upload, or else you're uploading new files and running the old one every time. After updating the filename I got the results I expected.